# retrieve 10 records in linq with join

Tags: web-services, linq-to-sql, xsd

i have a function in my webservice to retrive All posted from the database , and my code work fine :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public XmlDataDocument return_FanWall_Posts()
    {
        var reportXmlItems = from y in db.fanwalls
                             join x in db.users on y.user_id equals x.id
                             orderby y.id descending
                             select new XElement("All_Fanwall",
                                  new XElement("post_ID", y.id),
                                  new XElement("post_image", y.pic),
                                  new XElement("post", y.comment),
                                  new XElement("post_date", y.date)
                                  new XElement("User_Name", x.user_name),
                                  new XElement("User_image", x.pic_url)
                              );

        var reportXml = new XElement("All_Fanwall", reportXmlItems);
        XmlDataDocument m = new XmlDataDocument();
        m.LoadXml(reportXml.ToString());
        return m;
    }
```

Now i need to retrieve first 10 records then the next 10 , and this code not working the Results is Retrieving all records from the table :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public XmlDataDocument return_FanWall_Posts(int iBeginRowIndex, int iMaximumRows)
    {
        var reportXmlItems = from y in db.fanwalls
                             join x in db.users on y.user_id equals x.id
                             orderby y.id descending
                             select new XElement("All_Fanwall",
                                  new XElement("post_ID", y.id),
                                  new XElement("post_image", y.pic),
                                  new XElement("post", y.comment),
                                  new XElement("post_date", y.date)
                                  new XElement("User_Name", x.user_name),
                                  new XElement("User_image", x.pic_url)
                              );

        reportXmlItems.Skip(iBeginRowIndex).Take(iMaximumRows);
        var reportXml = new XElement("All_Fanwall", reportXmlItems);
        XmlDataDocument m = new XmlDataDocument();
        m.LoadXml(reportXml.ToString());
        return m;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parenthesise the query and tag the `Skip()` and `Take()` calls onto that instead...

```
var reportXmlItems = (from y in db.fanwalls
                      join x in db.users on y.user_id equals x.id
                      orderby y.id descending
                      select new XElement("All_Fanwall",
                                 new XElement("post_ID", y.id),
                                 new XElement("post_image", y.pic),
                                 new XElement("post", y.comment),
                                 new XElement("post_date", y.date),
                                 new XElement("User_Name", x.user_name),
                                 new XElement("User_image", x.pic_url)
                             )
                      ).Skip(iBeginRowIndex).Take(iMaximumRows);
```